# "Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument" error when trying to run app on android emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator, qemu

I have been trying to follow this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBzfsCFgGdo&list=PLDGYn1fFRgEN1zsbOLRCdapIZlb0Y9Bas&index=3

I run into the following error when trying to run the app on an emulator:

```
2021-07-22 02:14:47.311 442-442/? E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
2021-07-22 02:14:47.311 442-442/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2021-07-22 02:14:49.051 444-444/? E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
2021-07-22 02:14:49.051 444-444/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
```

All the solutions on the internet revolve around including "android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"" into the manifest file, but I have done that with no better outcome.

My code:

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.testapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(" http://192.168.1.246:5000/").build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "network not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
                TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                textView.setText(response.body().string());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testapp">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TestApp"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported = "false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Flask Server:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    print("request")
    return 'hello honey'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: instead of including a link to an external resource (the youtube link), include the actual steps you are following as part of the question. The link may break over time and not everyone may be able to access it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This error could be due to two reasons :

1. Either due to your android emulator / device version.
2. Due to some error in your java or xml file.

First, change your current minSdkVersion to some other version preferably below 23.
Then check your logcat whether it gives some error in your code. Most probably that could be an import error.

In my case, I changed my minSdkVersion from 26 to 17.
And it worked for me. Hopefully, it works for you as well.